# How do I paint a single treenode checkbox state to indeterminate

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

There are 3 states of a treenode with a checkbox, checked, unchecked and indeterminate (square).

The question I have is how do I draw the indeterminate state?

I have the following code which adds the 3 checkboxs to the treeview imagelist:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        treeView1.StateImageList = new System.Windows.Forms.ImageList();

        // populate the image list, using images from the System.Windows.Forms.CheckBoxRenderer class
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            // Create a bitmap which holds the relevent check box style
            // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404307.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkboxrenderer.aspx

            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(16, 16);
            System.Drawing.Graphics chkGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            switch (i)
            {
                // 0,1 - offset the checkbox slightly so it positions in the correct place
                case 0:
                    System.Windows.Forms.CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(chkGraphics, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 1), System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.Windows.Forms.CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(chkGraphics, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 1), System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.Windows.Forms.CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(chkGraphics, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 1), System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.MixedNormal);
                    break;
            }

            treeView1.StateImageList.Images.Add(bmp);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode n = new TreeNode("Root");
        n.SelectedImageIndex = 2;
        n.Nodes.Add("asd");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(n);
    }
  }
}
```

But when I set a treenode's `SelectedImageIndex = 2`

Nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

You have added `3` images to your `StateImageList` but `(int)CheckBoxState.MixedNormal` evaluates to `9`

There are **12** [`CheckBoxStates`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb177szy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) so you will need to either create more images or fold the index down to stay in your range:

```
treeView1.SelectedImageIndex = ((int)CheckBoxState.MixedNormal) / 4;
```

(You didn't account for the `disabled`, the `pressed`and the `hot`states in addition to the `normal`.)

You did set the `treeView1.StateImageList` to your `StateImageList` **and** the `treeView1.ImageList` to some other `Imagelist`, of course?

Comment: The other states wont matter as I only add those 3 to the StateImageList. The images gets added to the treeView1.StateImageList. Also I apologise but I should've made the code: SelectedImageIndex = 2;

Comment: So does it work as expected now when selecting nodes?